# set the number of vertices in boost:graph

Tags: boost, boost-graph

Given an empty boost::graph g, I want to set the number of vertices in this graph and add some edges then. But from the documentation, I cannot find related functions. All examples I found defines the size of vertices in initialization (like Graph g(10) defines a graph with 10 vertices). But I don't know the size when I define the graph. I want to first define a Graph g, and set the size later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to call the boost::add_vertex( graph ) method for each vertex you want.

Here is a nice place to start [Using C++ Boost's Graph Library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8812466/16582)

Note that you not HAVE to add the vertices one by one.  If all you care about are the edges, then add_edge() will add missing vertices for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, if I need to add 5000 vertices, I don't want to call 5000 times add_vertex(), it may be very slow.

Comment: Decide how long you can afford to spend on this task.  Write some test code.  Measure.  If it takes too long, then ask a question with some code and some measurements.

Comment: @ravenspoint I agree with LittleSweet - I've run a profiler and it seems memory allocation for the graph is taking 70% of my runtime. Is there anyway to preallocate for the number of edges that I will be adding?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably try a little dirty trick like:

```
add_edge(0,4999,g);
remove_edge(0,4999,g);
```

It exploits the side-effect of add_edge for adjacency_list, namely, the fact that BGL extends the vector of vertices if necessary.

Comment: I've tried this and verified with `num_vertices(Graph)` and it works!