# Boost Graph Library - Improve vertex initialization speed?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I have a graph with 5811 vertices; only known at run-time and thus could be anything but usually less than 6000. Initializing the vertices takes up a lot of time at 35 milliseconds.  I was wondering if anyone has a suggestion on how I can improve the vertex allocation speed ? I have looked through some other threads but it seems like there is no definite solution.

EDIT: It takes 35ms due to the amount of variables present in each vertex

```
//find amount of vertices required
//...   

//35ms
//initialize vertices
for (int i = 0; i < max + 1; i++)   boost::add_vertex(i, g);

//10ms
//fill up adjacency list and accumulate vertex information
for (int row = 0; row < label.rows; row++)  
    for (int col = 0; col < label.cols; col++)
    {
         //process data
    }
```

Comment: We can't see anything at all here. You never show /any/ of the relevant types. You don't tell us where the data come from etc. I'm very very happy to help you optimize code, but invisible code doesn't exist. Voting to close.

Comment: You can take a look at this [trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19358213/2876861) to accelerate the vertex allocations