# Creating a graph using Boost Graph library

Tags: c++, boost, graphviz, boost-graph

I am new to graph theory and graph concept.
I am workign on something, that requires me to create a mesh(Undirected graphs) with n number of nodes.
Once the structure is created, I would be running various algorithms on the structure, to find a shortest path from a node to other.
No for this I have decided to use Boost graph librabry.
I read through the online documentation. The online documentation is good but at the same time not sufficient.
I went through various examples online and everywhere, they import the graph from Graphviz.

If i am not wrong, we have to manually draw or write a dot program to get a graph in Graphviz and import in .dot format(Please correct me if i am wrong)

But is there a way in Boost where I could create a graph, instead of importing it from GraphViz?
And I would let user to decide the number of vertices in it, instead of pre-defining it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe not very correct, but I am giving a response a gave before.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3100220/202083

You can see how to programmaticaly add nodes and edges.

I hope this is enough for you to get started.