# What is required for a custom BGL graph to work with topological sort?

Tags: c++, boost-graph, c++-concepts, boost-property-map, customization-point

I've created a custom BGL graph model, like in this answer: [What is needed to use BGL algorithms on existing data structures ( edges and vertices as vector<Object *>)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193619/what-is-needed-to-use-bgl-algorithms-on-existing-data-structures-edges-and-ver).

It adapts a custom data structure for use with some Boost.Graph algorithms.

The linked answer was enough to get depth-first search working (**[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f24ad4fcb30d986)**) but I run into a problem when using [`boost::topological_sort`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/topological_sort.html):

```
std::list<V> rev_topo;
boost::topological_sort(g, back_inserter(rev_topo));
```

Gives: **[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78401f62a5ae0c90)**

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_categories.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/unordered/detail/implementation.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/unordered/detail/set.hpp:6,
                 from /usr/include/boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/unordered_set.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:21,
                 from /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::detail::has_vertex_property_type<Glue::MyGraph, mpl_::bool_<false> >, boost::detail::get_vertex_property_type<Glue::MyGraph>, boost::no_property>’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp:276:12:   required from ‘struct boost::vertex_property_type<Glue::MyGraph>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:201:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::vertex_property_map<Glue::MyGraph, boost::vertex_index_t>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/properties.hpp:212:10:   required from ‘struct boost::property_map<Glue::MyGraph, boost::vertex_index_t, void>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:415:69:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::override_const_property_t<int, boost::vertex_index_t, Glue::MyGraph, false>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:571:31:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::map_maker_helper<false, Glue::MyGraph, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >, boost::default_color_type, int>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:604:41:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:337:80:   required from ‘void boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Graph>::operator()(const Graph&, const ArgPack&) const [with ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >; Graph = Glue::MyGraph]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:342:5:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type boost::graph::depth_first_search_with_named_params(const Param0&, const ArgPack&) [with Param0 = Glue::MyGraph; ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:345:3:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type boost::depth_first_search(const Param0&, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&) [with Param0 = Glue::MyGraph; P = boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > >; T = boost::graph_visitor_t; R = boost::bgl_named_params<int, boost::buffer_param_t>; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp:65:23:   required from ‘void boost::topological_sort(VertexListGraph&, OutputIterator, const boost::bgl_named_params<P, T, R>&) [with VertexListGraph = Glue::MyGraph; OutputIterator = std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> >; P = int; T = boost::buffer_param_t; R = boost::no_property]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp:71:21:   required from ‘void boost::topological_sort(VertexListGraph&, OutputIterator) [with VertexListGraph = Glue::MyGraph; OutputIterator = std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> >]’
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:139:55:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:38:31: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::detail::has_vertex_property_type<Glue::MyGraph, mpl_::bool_<false> >, boost::detail::get_vertex_property_type<Glue::MyGraph>, boost::no_property>::f_’ {aka ‘struct boost::no_property’}
   38 |     typedef typename f_::type type;
      |                               ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:23,
                 from /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::detail::override_const_property_t<int, boost::vertex_index_t, Glue::MyGraph, false>’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:571:31:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::map_maker_helper<false, Glue::MyGraph, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >, boost::default_color_type, int>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:604:41:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::map_maker<Glue::MyGraph, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >, boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map, boost::default_color_type>’
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:620:7:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Graph, class ArgPack> typename boost::detail::map_maker<Graph, ArgPack, boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map, boost::default_color_type>::map_type boost::detail::make_property_map_from_arg_pack_gen<boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map, boost::default_color_type>::operator()<Graph, ArgPack>(const Graph&, const ArgPack&) const [with Graph = Glue::MyGraph; ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:337:80:   required from ‘void boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Graph>::operator()(const Graph&, const ArgPack&) const [with ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >; Graph = Glue::MyGraph]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:342:5:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type boost::graph::depth_first_search_with_named_params(const Param0&, const ArgPack&) [with Param0 = Glue::MyGraph; ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:345:3:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type boost::depth_first_search(const Param0&, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&) [with Param0 = Glue::MyGraph; P = boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > >; T = boost::graph_visitor_t; R = boost::bgl_named_params<int, boost::buffer_param_t>; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp:65:23:   required from ‘void boost::topological_sort(VertexListGraph&, OutputIterator, const boost::bgl_named_params<P, T, R>&) [with VertexListGraph = Glue::MyGraph; OutputIterator = std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> >; P = int; T = boost::buffer_param_t; R = boost::no_property]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp:71:21:   required from ‘void boost::topological_sort(VertexListGraph&, OutputIterator) [with VertexListGraph = Glue::MyGraph; OutputIterator = std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> >]’
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:139:55:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:415:69: error: no type named ‘const_type’ in ‘struct boost::property_map<Glue::MyGraph, boost::vertex_index_t, void>’
  415 |       typedef typename boost::property_map<Graph, Prop>::const_type result_type;
      |                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:5:
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Graph>::operator()(const Graph&, const ArgPack&) const [with ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >; Graph = Glue::MyGraph]’:
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:342:5:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type boost::graph::depth_first_search_with_named_params(const Param0&, const ArgPack&) [with Param0 = Glue::MyGraph; ArgPack = boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const ArgPack&)>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:345:3:   required from ‘typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type boost::depth_first_search(const Param0&, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&) [with Param0 = Glue::MyGraph; P = boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > >; T = boost::graph_visitor_t; R = boost::bgl_named_params<int, boost::buffer_param_t>; typename boost::result_of<boost::graph::detail::depth_first_search_impl<Param0>(Param0, const typename boost::detail::convert_bgl_params_to_boost_parameter<boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base> >::type&)>::type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp:65:23:   required from ‘void boost::topological_sort(VertexListGraph&, OutputIterator, const boost::bgl_named_params<P, T, R>&) [with VertexListGraph = Glue::MyGraph; OutputIterator = std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> >; P = int; T = boost::buffer_param_t; R = boost::no_property]’
/usr/include/boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp:71:21:   required from ‘void boost::topological_sort(VertexListGraph&, OutputIterator) [with VertexListGraph = Glue::MyGraph; OutputIterator = std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> >]’
/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:139:55:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp:337:80: error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::detail::make_property_map_from_arg_pack_gen<boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map, boost::default_color_type>) (const Glue::MyGraph&, const boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::visitor, const boost::topo_sort_visitor<std::back_insert_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<YourLibrary::myVertex*> > > >, boost::parameter::aux::arg_list<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::graph::keywords::tag::buffer, const int>, boost::parameter::aux::empty_arg_list> >&)’
  337 |                                     boost::detail::make_color_map_from_arg_pack(g, arg_pack),
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:23,
                 from /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:620:7: note: candidate: ‘template<class Graph, class ArgPack> typename boost::detail::map_maker<Graph, ArgPack, MapTag, ValueType>::map_type boost::detail::make_property_map_from_arg_pack_gen<MapTag, ValueType>::operator()(const Graph&, const ArgPack&) const [with Graph = Graph; ArgPack = ArgPack; MapTag = boost::graph::keywords::tag::color_map; ValueType = boost::default_color_type]’
  620 |       operator()(const Graph& g, const ArgPack& ap) const {
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/graph/named_function_params.hpp:620:7: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
```

What additional requirements must the "glue" layer meet in order to use `boost::topological_sort`? Internally, topological sort uses `depth_first_search`, but it appears it may require a vertex index map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you correctly surmised, the error novel is telling you that there is no index map. That is [required for the default color map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/topological_sort.html#boost-common-heading-doc-spacer:%7E:text=and%20using%20the%20i_map%20for%20the%20index%20map):

> ***UTIL/OUT***: `color_map(ColorMap color)` This is used by the algorithm to
> keep track of its progress through the graph. The type `ColorMap` must
> be a model of Read/Write Property Map and its key type must be the
> graph's vertex descriptor type and the value type of the color map
> must model `ColorValue`.
>
> ***Default***: an `iterator_property_map` created from
> a `std::vector` of `default_color_type` of size `num_vertices(g)` and **using
> the `i_map` for the index map.**

Indeed, the index map isn't even required if you fulfill the color map requirement yourself: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faba663eb3388502)**

```
std::map<V, boost::default_color_type> vertex_colors;
boost::topological_sort(
        g,
        back_inserter(rev_topo),
        boost::color_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(vertex_colors))
    );
```

### More Musings: Teaching BGL Vertex Indices

Now, many algorithms require an index-map, and many get much more convenient, just like above, when your graph model **does** have a vertex index map.

A vertex index should map the vertex descriptors to integral numbers `[0, n)` (where `n` is the total number of vertices). In the case of the example graph model, a trivial index would be the element index into the vector of vertices.

So, you could also express the index map as:

```
auto idmap = boost::make_function_property_map<V>([&](V v) {
    auto match = std::find(begin(vv), end(vv), v);
    assert(match != end(vv));
    return std::distance(begin(vv), match);
});
```

Now you can call the algorithm relying on their default color map: **[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d0059312f2774ea)**

```
boost::topological_sort(
        g,
        back_inserter(rev_topo),
        boost::vertex_index_map(idmap)
    );
```

That's not a big win, since now we still need optional named params, and even need the `idmap` contraption which seems more complicated than the `vertex_colors` map before?

### Simplifying / Integrating Into The Model

We can make it better by teaching the BGL how to get our property maps from the Glue::MyGraph model.

Property Maps will be found by BGL using

- the type trait `boost::property_map<Graph, Tag>` which tells BGL about the type of the propertymap.

  Here, `Tag` would be e.g. `boost::vertex_index_t` for the vertex index map.
- the accessor functions

  - `get(tag, graph)`

    Returning a copy of the property-map of that type
  - `get(tag_type, graph, descriptor)`

  For writable property maps there's also the corresponding `put` accessor, but I'll leave it for brevity. See the documentation for [Boost PropertyMap Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html) for more information on the features of that library.

Let's do that. We start by moving the `idmap` generator to our `MyGraph` model, so we don't need to know about the implementation details anymore:

```
    auto idmap() const {
        using V = YourLibrary::myVertex const*;
        return boost::make_function_property_map<V>([this](V v) {
            auto match = std::find(begin(_vertices), end(_vertices), v);
            assert(match != end(_vertices));
            return std::distance(begin(_vertices), match);
        });
    }
```

That means you could simply call `g.idmap()` to get the same propery map. However, we wanted the library to "magically" know. So, first we specialize the trait:

```
namespace boost {
    template <> struct property_map<Glue::MyGraph, boost::vertex_index_t> {
        using const_type = decltype(std::declval<Glue::MyGraph>().idmap());
    };
}
```

It's a delight of c++14 that we can deduce all these types. Only remaining step: the accessor functions, which are again ADL-enabled customization points, so we put them into our Glue namespace:

```
    auto get(boost::vertex_index_t, MyGraph const& g) {
        return g.idmap();
    }
    auto get(boost::vertex_index_t, MyGraph const& g, YourLibrary::myVertex const* v) {
        return g.idmap()[v];
    }
}  // namespace Glue
```

### Proof Of The Pudding

Now, since the library "just understands" vertex indices for our model, we can enjoy the algorithms that need one without any additional help:

```
std::list<V> order;
boost::topological_sort(g, back_inserter(order));
```

And we can exercise the other accessor for fun:

```
std::cout << "Topo order:\n";
order.reverse(); // output is reversed
for (auto v : order)
    std::cout << "Vertex index:" << get(boost::vertex_index, g, v)
              << " name:" << v->name << "\n";
```

In your own (non-generic, library) code you would probably write

```
auto idmap = g.idmap(); // or
auto idmap = get(boost::vertex_index, g, v);
```

And use `idmap[v]` to get values instead.

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68c36d9949d529b0)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/function_property_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace YourLibrary {
    struct myVertex {
        myVertex(std::string n) : name(std::move(n)) {}
        std::string name;
    };

    struct myEdge {
        myVertex* _s = nullptr;
        myVertex* _t = nullptr;

        [[nodiscard]] myVertex* source() const { return _s; }
        [[nodiscard]] myVertex* target() const { return _t; }
    };

    using Vertices = std::vector<myVertex *>;
    using Edges = std::vector<myEdge *>;
}  // namespace YourLibrary

namespace Glue {

    struct MyGraph {
        struct EdgeOrder {
            template <typename A, typename B>
                bool operator()(A const* a, B const* b) const { return source(a) < source(b); }
            private:
            static auto source(YourLibrary::myVertex const* v) { return v; }
            static auto source(YourLibrary::myEdge const* e) { return e->source(); }
        };

        using Vertices = YourLibrary::Vertices;
        using Edges = YourLibrary::Edges;

        Vertices& _vertices;
        Edges& _edges;

        auto idmap() const {
            using V = YourLibrary::myVertex const*;
            return boost::make_function_property_map<V>([this](V v) {
                auto match = std::find(begin(_vertices), end(_vertices), v);
                assert(match != end(_vertices));
                return std::distance(begin(_vertices), match);
            });
        }

        MyGraph(Vertices& vv, Edges& ee) : _vertices(vv), _edges(ee)  { 
            assert(std::is_sorted(_edges.begin(), _edges.end(), EdgeOrder{}));
        }
    };
}  // namespace Glue

namespace boost {

    template <> struct graph_traits<Glue::MyGraph> {
        // Due to Graph concept
        using vertex_descriptor      = YourLibrary::myVertex*;
        using edge_descriptor        = YourLibrary::myEdge*;
        using directed_category      = directed_tag;
        using edge_parallel_category = allow_parallel_edge_tag;
        static vertex_descriptor null_vertex() { return nullptr; }

        // Due to Vertex List concept
        struct traversal_category : vertex_list_graph_tag, incidence_graph_tag { };
        using vertex_iterator        = Glue::MyGraph::Vertices::const_iterator;
        using vertices_size_type     = std::size_t;

        // Due to Incidence Graph concept
        using out_edge_iterator = Glue::MyGraph::Edges::const_iterator;
        using degree_size_type = std::size_t;
    };

}  // namespace boost

namespace Glue {
    // Due to Vertex List concept
    auto vertices(MyGraph const& g) {
        return std::make_pair(g._vertices.begin(), g._vertices.end());
    }

    std::size_t num_vertices(MyGraph const& g) {
        return g._vertices.size();
    }

    // Due to Incidence Graph concept
    auto source(YourLibrary::myEdge const* e, MyGraph const& /*g*/) {
        return e->source();
    }
    auto target(YourLibrary::myEdge const* e, MyGraph const& /*g*/) {
        return e->target();
    }

    auto out_edges(YourLibrary::myVertex const* v, MyGraph const& g) {
        return std::equal_range(g._edges.begin(), g._edges.end(), v, MyGraph::EdgeOrder{});;
    }
    std::size_t out_degree(YourLibrary::myVertex const* v, MyGraph const& g) {
        auto oee = std::equal_range(g._edges.begin(), g._edges.end(), v, MyGraph::EdgeOrder{});
        return std::distance(oee.first, oee.second);
    }

    auto get(boost::vertex_index_t, MyGraph const& g) {
        return g.idmap();
    }
    auto get(boost::vertex_index_t, MyGraph const& g, YourLibrary::myVertex const* v) {
        return g.idmap()[v];
    }
}  // namespace Glue

namespace boost {
    template <> struct property_map<Glue::MyGraph, boost::vertex_index_t> {
        using const_type = decltype(std::declval<Glue::MyGraph>().idmap());
    };
}

int main() {
    // I hate manual memory management, so let's own some objects
    auto a = std::make_unique<YourLibrary::myVertex>("a");
    auto b = std::make_unique<YourLibrary::myVertex>("b");
    auto c = std::make_unique<YourLibrary::myVertex>("c");
    auto ab = std::make_unique<YourLibrary::myEdge>(YourLibrary::myEdge{a.get(), b.get()});
    auto cb = std::make_unique<YourLibrary::myEdge>(YourLibrary::myEdge{c.get(), b.get()});

    // These were given in your question:
    YourLibrary::Vertices vv { a.get(), b.get(), c.get() };
    YourLibrary::Edges ee { ab.get(), cb.get() };

    // this is the glue required to fulfill the BGL concepts:
    using boost::make_iterator_range;

    Glue::MyGraph g(vv, ee);
    for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(v, g)))
            std::cout << "out edge ("
                      << source(e, g)->name << " -> "
                      << target(e, g)->name << ")\n";

    // this is showing that you can now BFS on it
    using V = boost::graph_traits<Glue::MyGraph>::vertex_descriptor;
    V start_vertex = a.get();
    std::map<V, boost::default_color_type> color_data;

    boost::breadth_first_search(g, start_vertex,
        boost::visitor(boost::default_bfs_visitor {})
            .color_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(color_data)));

    boost::depth_first_search(g, boost::default_dfs_visitor {},
        boost::make_assoc_property_map(color_data), start_vertex);

    // named params
    boost::depth_first_search(g,
        boost::visitor(boost::default_dfs_visitor {})
            .color_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(color_data))
            .root_vertex(start_vertex));

    std::list<V> order;
    boost::topological_sort(g, back_inserter(order));

    std::cout << "Topo order:\n";
    order.reverse(); // output is reversed

    auto idmap = g.idmap();
    for (auto v : order)
        std::cout << "Vertex index:" << idmap[v] << " name:" << v->name << "\n";
}
```

Printing

```
out edge (a -> b)
out edge (c -> b)
Topo order:
Vertex index:2 name:c
Vertex index:0 name:a
Vertex index:1 name:b
```

Comment: I just realized I had completely forgotten about the edge ordering invariant in this graph model, so I [added a constructor check](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66352925/revisions) in the final listing, just to avoid nasty surprises.