# How do I Generically Access the Boost Graph Bundled Properties?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-graph

I am writing a c++ template to read in weighted graphs of the formats [GraphViz](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/read_graphviz.html) and [GraphML](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/graph/doc/read_graphml.html).

The difficulty is that I use different graph types with different vertex/edge bundles, they could look something like

```cpp
struct EdgeBundle_1 {
    double weight = 1.;
};

struct EdgeBundle_2 {
    double weight = 2.;
    int some_int;
};

using Graph_1 = typename boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS,
                                               boost::vecS,
                                               boost::undirectedS,
                                               VertexBundle,
                                               EdgeBundle_1>;

using Graph_2 = typename boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS,
                                               boost::vecS,
                                               boost::undirectedS,
                                               VertexBundle,
                                               EdgeBundle_2>;
```

Now I want to access the edge bundle of an arbitrary `Graph`, so I have to replace `&EdgeBundle_1` in the following code that only works for `Graph_1`

```cpp
template <typename Graph>
void do_sth_with_bundled_weight(Graph& g){
    boost::dynamic_properties dp(boost::ignore_other_properties);
    dp.property("weight", boost::get(&EdgeBundle_1::weight, g));

    ... // here, I read in the graph via `boost::read_graphml(if_stream, g, dp);`
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything other than how to access the *type* of a bundled property, at the very bottom of [this boost docs page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html).

I'm grateful for any help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With BGL the real question is "how to do anything not-generically" :)

So, you can do precisely as boost does. All the algorithms take [property-maps](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html) which abstract away the relation between graph elements and their properties.

Often this will be about temporary properties specific to the algorithm, but there's nothing that prevents you from using it in more places.

The best thing is, you already **have** the property map, and it's precisely the variable part:`get(&EdgeBundle_1::weight, g)`, so instead just take that as a parameter:

```
template <typename Graph, typename WeightMap>
void write_graph(std::ostream& os, Graph& g, WeightMap weight_map) {
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("weight", weight_map);

    boost::write_graphml(os, g, dp);
}

template <typename Graph, typename WeightMap>
void read_graph(Graph& g, WeightMap weight_map) {
    boost::dynamic_properties dp(boost::ignore_other_properties);
    dp.property("weight", weight_map);

    std::ifstream ifs("input.xml", std::ios::binary);
    g.clear();
    boost::read_graphml(ifs, g, dp);
}
```

You can even make it default to the library default edge weight map:

```
template <typename Graph> void read_graph(Graph& g) {
    return read_graph(g, get(boost::edge_weight, g));
}

template <typename Graph> void write_graph(std::ostream& os, Graph& g) {
    return write_graph(os, g, get(boost::edge_weight, g));
}
```

### Demo: Reading and Comparing Equal

Roundtripping the following XML both Graph_1 and Graph_2 and checking  equality:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key id="key0" for="edge" attr.name="weight" attr.type="double" />
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected" parse.nodeids="free" parse.edgeids="canonical" parse.order="nodesfirst">
    <node id="n0">
    </node>
    <node id="n1">
    </node>
    <node id="n2">
    </node>
    <node id="n3">
    </node>
    <node id="n4">
    </node>
    <node id="n5">
    </node>
    <node id="n6">
    </node>
    <node id="n7">
    </node>
    <node id="n8">
    </node>
    <node id="n9">
    </node>
    <edge id="e0" source="n0" target="n7">
      <data key="key0">2.2</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e1" source="n7" target="n3">
      <data key="key0">3.3</data>
    </edge>
    <edge id="e2" source="n3" target="n2">
      <data key="key0">4.4</data>
    </edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

[image]

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6d1d507189d6f12)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphml.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct VertexBundle {};

struct EdgeBundle_1 {
    double weight = 1.;
};

struct EdgeBundle_2 {
    double weight = 2.;
    int some_int;
};

using Graph_1 = typename boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, VertexBundle, EdgeBundle_1>;

using Graph_2 = typename boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, VertexBundle, EdgeBundle_2>;

template <typename Graph, typename WeightMap>
void write_graph(std::ostream& os, Graph& g, WeightMap weight_map) {
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("weight", weight_map);

    boost::write_graphml(os, g, dp);
}

template <typename Graph, typename WeightMap>
void read_graph(std::istream& is, Graph& g, WeightMap weight_map) {
    boost::dynamic_properties dp(boost::ignore_other_properties);
    dp.property("weight", weight_map);

    g.clear();
    boost::read_graphml(is, g, dp);
}

template <typename Graph> void read_graph(std::istream& is, Graph& g) {
    return read_graph(is, g, get(boost::edge_weight, g));
}

template <typename Graph> void write_graph(std::ostream& os, Graph& g) {
    return write_graph(os, g, get(boost::edge_weight, g));
}

extern std::string const demo_xml;

int main() {
    Graph_1 g1;
    Graph_2 g2;
    auto w1 = get(&EdgeBundle_1::weight, g1);
    auto w2 = get(&EdgeBundle_2::weight, g2);

    auto roundtrip = [](auto g, auto w) {
        {
            std::istringstream is(demo_xml);
            read_graph(is, g, w);
        }

        std::ostringstream os;
        write_graph(os, g, w);
        return os.str();
    };

    auto xml1 = roundtrip(Graph_1{}, w1);
    auto xml2 = roundtrip(Graph_2{}, w2);

    std::cout << "Equal:" << std::boolalpha << (xml1 == xml2) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Equal:true
```

### BONUS

To have more automation, you can [tell BGL about your property maps with traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66352055/what-is-required-for-a-custom-bgl-graph-to-work-with-topological-sort/66352925#answer-66352925:%7E:text=We%20can%20make%20it%20better%20by%20teaching%20the%20BGL%20how%20to%20get%20our%20property%20maps) so you don't have to manually specify it at anymore.

**Update** Added this as a finger exercise. Warning: this is not for the faint of heart. It my look innocous in terms of lines of code, but it is actually pretty dense and uses many advanced and subtle library and language features.

In a custom namespace (e.g. `MyLib`), we create a wrapper type that we can customize for:

```
template <typename Impl> struct Graph {
    Impl&       graph() { return _impl; };
    Impl const& graph() const { return _impl; };
    void clear() { _impl.clear(); }
  private:
    Impl _impl;
};
```

Next, we delegate common BGL operations:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename... T> static auto& fwd_impl(Graph<T...>& g) {
        return g.graph();
    }
    template <typename... T> static auto const& fwd_impl(Graph<T...> const& g) {
        return g.graph();
    }
    template <typename T> static decltype(auto) fwd_impl(T&& v) {
        return std::forward<T>(v);
    }
}

#define DELEGATE_ONE(r, _, name)                                               \
    template <typename... Args>                                                \
    static inline decltype(auto) name(Args&&... args) {                        \
        return (boost::name)(                                                  \
            detail::fwd_impl(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args))...);          \
    }
#define DELEGATE(...)                                                          \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DELEGATE_ONE, _,                                     \
                          BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))

    DELEGATE(add_vertex, add_edge, vertices, edges, num_vertices, num_edges,
             out_edges, out_degree, get, source, target, vertex)
#undef DELEGATE
#undef DELEGATE_ONE
```

Yup. That's a lot. Basically, we delegate all the named free functions if ADL associates our namespace, and we forward all the arguments to the boost version unmodified **except** for the `Graph<>` wrapper which is replaced by its `_impl`.

Next, we add the twist we were looking for:

```
// The crux: overriding the edge_weight map to access the bundle
template <typename Impl> auto get(boost::edge_weight_t, Graph<Impl>& g) {
    auto bundle_map = boost::get(boost::edge_bundle, g.graph());
    auto accessor   = [](auto& bundle) -> decltype(auto) {
        return access_edge_weight(bundle);
    };

    return boost::make_transform_value_property_map(accessor, bundle_map);
}
```

We re-define the original graphs using the wrapper:

```
using Graph_1 = Graph<GraphImpl_1>;
using Graph_2 = Graph<GraphImpl_2>;
```

#### Traits

The traits are not free functions and need to be outside our namespace. I use c++17 syntax for brevity:

```
template <typename Impl>
struct boost::graph_traits<MyLib::Graph<Impl>> : boost::graph_traits<Impl> {};

template <typename Impl, typename Property>
struct boost::graph_property<MyLib::Graph<Impl>, Property>
    : boost::graph_property<Impl, Property> {};

template <typename Impl, typename Property>
struct boost::property_map<MyLib::Graph<Impl>, Property>
    : boost::property_map<Impl, Property> {};
```

There. That tells BGL that our graph is our implementation type for traits/property maps.

However, **we did override** `edge_weight_t` map:

```
template <typename Impl>
struct boost::property_map<MyLib::Graph<Impl>, boost::edge_weight_t> {
    using Wrapper = MyLib::Graph<Impl>;
    using type = decltype(MyLib::get(boost::edge_weight, std::declval<Wrapper&>()));
    using const_type = decltype(MyLib::get(boost::edge_weight, std::declval<Wrapper const&>()));
};
```

*(Again liberally using c++14 features for brevity.)*

#### The Proof

All this magic buys us that now we don't have to provide a property map, instead it gets detected automatically:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6564a6c7cdb535e1)**

```
int main() {
    auto roundtrip = [](auto g) {
        std::istringstream is(demo_xml);
        read_graph(is, g);

        std::ostringstream os;
        write_graph(os, g);
        return os.str();
    };

    std::cerr << "Equal:" << std::boolalpha
              << (roundtrip(MyLib::Graph_1{}) == roundtrip(MyLib::Graph_2{}))
              << "\n";
}
```

Still prints

```
Equal:true
```

Comment: Added a ridiculous tour-de-force to demonstrate automatic property-map detection for a custom `Graph<>` wrapper: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/326fd321f127c4a7)**